# Protractor & Chrome - Waiting for Input element class attribute to change/disappear fails intermittently

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I am using protractor 4.0.10 to test an angular 1.5.10 with chromedriverVersion: 2.26.436382

My test is basically checking if an inputbox behaves properly when typing an invalid email, and then when the email is correct.

For the first part, I wait until ng-invalid-email is present in the class attribute (and then test for it). This step always work fine.

After that, I clear() the inputbox and add a valid email to it. After doing so I wait to see if ng-invalid-email disappear using a helper function:

```js
function waitClassValueToDisappear(fieldElement, class_value) {
    var local_class = class_value;
    browser.wait(function() {
      return element(by.model(fieldElement)).getAttribute('class').then(function(value) {
          //console.log(value ,' <> ', local_class);
          return value.indexOf(local_class) < 0;
      });
  }, 5000);
}
```

Most of the time, this seems to work properly but sometimes it times out. After doing some debugging, I found ng-invalid-email is kept as class attribute until the test above times out.

The test case screenshot shows the valid email in the inputbox and the inputbox has a blue frame (we are using red frame when ng-invalid-email is present).

I wonder if there is any problem in the way protractor queries the attributes of an ui element that could cause the behaviour above (or maybe this is provided by webdriver/selenium)?

If I uncomment the console.log above I see this when the error happens:

> form-control  (..lots of other values..) ng-not-modified-remove-active
>   ng-modified-add-active ng-valid-error-add-active
>   ng-invalid-pattern-remove-active ng-valid-pattern-add-active
>   ng-invalid-remove-active ng-valid-add-active  <>  ng-invalid-email (*
>   once or twice at the beginning)

and then mutiples:

> form-control
>   ng-untouched ng-dirty ng-not-empty ng-invalid-email ng-valid-required
>   ng-invalid-pattern ng-valid ng-valid-error ng-modified  <> 
>   ng-invalid-email (.... repeating until it times out)

So it looks like the object class attribute has changed, but ng-invalid-email is still present, even though the screenshot tells me it is valid.

For reference, the full test case is as follows:

```
it(this.description, function() {
  ...
  utils.waitModelExist(cs.alerts.ADD_EMAIL_INPUT);
  browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(app.getAppElementByModel(cs.alerts.ADD_EMAIL_INPUT)), TIME_TO_WAIT_MILLISECONDS);
  app.getAppElementByModel(cs.alerts.ADD_EMAIL_INPUT).sendKeys('username');
  actions.waitClassValueToBePresent(cs.alerts.ADD_EMAIL_INPUT, 'ng-invalid-email');
  expect(app.getAppElementByModel(cs.alerts.ADD_EMAIL_INPUT).getAttribute('class')).toContain('ng-invalid-email');
  app.getAppElementByModel(cs.alerts.ADD_EMAIL_INPUT).clear();
  //actions.waitForAttributeValue(cs.alerts.ADD_EMAIL_INPUT, '');
  app.getAppElementByModel(cs.alerts.ADD_EMAIL_INPUT).sendKeys('username@nowitis.valid');
  //actions.waitForAttributeValue(cs.alerts.ADD_EMAIL_INPUT, 'username@nowitis.valid');
  actions.waitClassValueToDisappear(cs.alerts.ADD_EMAIL_INPUT, 'ng-invalid-email');
  expect(app.getAppElementByModel(cs.alerts.ADD_EMAIL_INPUT).getAttribute('class')).not.toContain('ng-invalid-email');
});
```

Any ideas? Is this a protractor problem?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you don't need to trigger the JS validation somehow? i.e. just clicking somewhere on the app

Comment: I tried to add a click() somewhere else, as well as send a TAB so the input would lose the focus and still didn't work. Is that what you meant ?

Comment: Yea that's what I meant.  Only reason I suggested was because for our angular app the errors usually show up instantly, but to remove them usually needs a way to re-run the validation (which typically happens when the input loses focus or something).  Interesting...